# Автоматизация рутинных задач

Tags: python, python-3.x, автоматизация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните пожалуйста откуда в функции появляются параметры guest и item ?
Читал английскую версию ответа ,недопонял!!

Comment: и вот еще непонятка, предположим что над этим словарем allGuest  еще один такой же словарь ,но назывется он guest = {.........},Какой словарь будет в приоритете для функции totalBrought

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011347/automate-the-boring-stuff-with-python-nested-dictionaries-and-lists

Comment: На такой вопрос так и хочется ответить - от верблюда!  Что значит откуда появляются? Автор так решил.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Английская версия - это та-же самая программа, но другой вопрос (и - соответственно - другой ответ.)

Параметры функции могут иметь *любые имена*, например функцию для суммы двух чисел вы можете определить как

```
def suma(a, b):
    return a + b
```

или как

```
def suma(ivan, ola):
    return ivan + ola
```

Когда затем напишете

```
x = 6
y = 4
z = suma(x, y)
```

в обоих случаях получите в переменной `z` значение `10`, потому что:

- `x` будет присоединено первому параметру, какого бы имел имени (`a` или `ivan`),   и
- `y` второму, какого бы имел имени (`b` или `ola`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Теперь к вашему вопросу в комментарии:

Так что в команде

```
print(' - Apples          ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 
                                  'apples')))
```

функция вызывается как

```
totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')
```

то словарь `allGuests` - а не какой-то другой - будет соответствовать параметру `guests` в определении функции `totalBrought()`, т.е. в определении

```
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
    return numBrought
```

Ни какого приоритета просто нет - какой словарь задаете, с таким будет функция `totalBrought()` работать (т.к. он будет присоединен и имени `guests` в определении функции `totalBrought()`).

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!После вашего объяснения все оказалось очевидным.Не знаю как я не увидел этого!